# LINQ: Get a total count from a nested list inside projection

Tags: c#, linq, count, nested-properties

I have the following LINQ statement:

```
var branchStatus = (from b in context.Branches
    join l in context.Lobbies on b.BranchId equals l.BranchId into branchLobbyDetails
    from bl in branchLobbyDetails.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where (branches.Count == 0 || branches.Contains(bl.BranchId)) 
        && b.IsActive 
        && (bl == null ? true : bl.IsActive && !bl.IsArchived)
    group bl by new { b.BranchId, b.BranchName } into grouped
    select new BranchStatusDetailsDto
    {
        Id = grouped.Key.BranchId.ToString(),
        BranchName = grouped.Key.BranchName,
        WaitingInLobby = (grouped.Any() && grouped.First() != null) ? grouped.Count(l => l.Status == 1).ToString() : defaultEmpty,
        TotalPSProvided = (grouped.Any() && grouped.First() != null) ? grouped.Where(l => l.Status != 6).Select(l => l.ServicesProvided).Count().ToString() : defaultEmpty,
        AverageAssistTime = (grouped.Any() && grouped.First() != null) ? grouped.Where(l => l.Status == 5).Select(l => (TimeSpan)(l.CompletedTime - l.AssistedTime)).Average().ToString() : string.Empty    
    });
```

I'm basically collecting stats for each of the branches in the list. In the projection statement, the the first calculation (`WaitingInLobby`) is Ok, I'm having issues with the `TotalPSProvided` and `AverageAssistTime`.

For each branch, there can be multiple Lobby records and each Lobby record can have 0 or more `ServicesProvided` entries. With `TotalPSProvided` I want to get the total of that per the branch, but what I'm getting is not correct - it seems like with the current query it gives the number of lobby records as the `TotalPSProvided`.

How can I modify the statement to return the correct stat?

Adding the entity definitions:

```
public partial class Branch
{
    public int BranchId { get; set; }
    public string BranchName { get; set; }
    public string BranchCode { get; set; }
    public string TimeZoneId { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
}

    public partial class Lobby
{
    public Lobby()
    {
        this.ServicesRequested = new List<ServicesRequested>();
        this.ServicesProvided = new List<ServicesProvided>();
    }

    [Key]
    [Required]
    public long LobbyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Branch")]
    public int BranchId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserRequested")]
    public int? RequestedUserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("GroupRequested")]
    public int? RequestedGroupId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AddedByUser")]
    public int? AddedByUserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AssistedByUser")]
    public int? AssistedByUserId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(1000)]
    public string Comments { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime? AddedTime { get; set; }


    public DateTime? AssistedTime { get; set; }


    public DateTime? CompletedTime { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }


    public bool IsArchived { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey("LobbyStatus")]
    public int Status { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    [Required]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    //[ForeignKey("Appointment")]
    public long? FkAppointmentId { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(150)]
    public string Notes { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(2)]
    //[Required]
    [ForeignKey("PreferredLanguage")]
    public string PreferredLanguageKey { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool ClosedByAutoWrapUp { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Stores the requested services as a pre-calculated string to support sorting
    /// </summary>
    public string RequestedServices { get; set; }


    public DateTime? AddedLocalTime { get; set; }


    public DateTime? AssistedLocalTime { get; set; }


    public DateTime? CompletedLocalTime { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(4)]
    public string AccountNoLastFourDigits { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Branch Branch { get; set; }
    public virtual User UserRequested { get; set; }
    public virtual Group GroupRequested { get; set; }
    public virtual User AssistedByUser { get; set; }
    public virtual Language PreferredLanguage { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ServicesProvided> ServicesProvided { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ServicesRequested> ServicesRequested { get; set; }
}

public partial class ServicesProvided
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public long ServiceProvidedId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Lobby")]
    public long LobbyId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Service")]
    public int ServiceId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Lobby Lobby { get; set; }

    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: could you add your entities? `Branches` and `Lobbies`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a typo in your query, you're counting `ServicesProvided` instead of adding them up, you're doing this :

```
TotalPSProvided = (grouped.Any() && grouped.First() != null) ? grouped.Where(l => l.Status != 6).Select(l => l.ServicesProvided).Count().ToString() : defaultEmpty,
```

instead of this :

```
TotalPSProvided = (grouped.Any() && grouped.First() != null) ? grouped.Where(l => l.Status != 6).Sum(l => l.ServicesProvided).ToString() : defaultEmpty,
```

Comment: Thanks, this was my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The problem for `TotalPSProvided` is in the line:

```
grouped.Where(l => l.Status != 6).Select(l => l.ServicesProvided).Count()
```

Here you are simply counting the number of (branch,lobby) pairs that fulfill the where condition.

Rework into:

```
TotalPSProvided = (grouped.Any() && grouped.First() != null) 
                    ? grouped.Where(l => l.Status != 6)
                             .Sum(l => l.ServicesProvided.Count()).ToString() 
                    : defaultEmpty,
```